# Find particular rows in Graphlab or Python

Tags: python, graphlab, sframe

In Graphlab,

I am working with a small subset of movies from a larger list.

```
  movieIds_5K_np = LL_features_SCD_min.to_numpy()[:,0]
  ratings_33K_np = ratings_33K.to_numpy()
```

`movieIds_5K_np` is an array containing my movieIds. `ratings_33K_np' is an array with FOUR columns whose second columns contains movie Ids for ALL movies.

I need to select only the rows in `ratings_33K_np` whose id exist in `movieIds_5K_np'.

I tried this approach but it doesn't seems to be working:

```
 ratings_5K_np = ratings_33K_np[ratings_33K_np[:,2]==movieIds_5K_np]
```

How can I do this in Graphlab or by using some Python libraries? I should say that originally `ratings_33K` and `movieIds_5K` were imported as SFrame.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you have 2 `sframe`s, you can do a `join`, like so:

```
ratings_5K = LL_features_SCD_min[['id_column_name']].join(ratings_33K, on='id_column_name', how='left')
```

As far as I understood from your code, the `LL_features_SCD_min` is the `sframe` corresponding to your miniset (5K data). So you just take the IDs that you want and left join them with the entire dataset, thus obtaining a new `sframe` with only the IDs that you wanted. Just substitute your id column name and there you go.

For more information regarding how `join` work within `graphlab`, consider checking the [documentation](https://dato.com/products/create/docs/generated/graphlab.SFrame.join.html) on `SFrame`.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, it worked pretty well. Can I know the difference between 'left' and 'inner'. I would have used 'inner' join in this case shouldn't have you mentioned 'left'

Comment: `left` join assures you will have all rows from the `LL_features` sframe in your result (with null values for absent rows in `ratings_33` sframe), while `inner` join will return only the rows contained in both `sframe`s, dropping out values from `LL_features` sframe if they are not present in `ratings_33K` sframe. Depending on what you need, you might use one or another. For a visual explanation of types of `join`, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706437/whats-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-and-full-join) answer

Comment: Amazing explanations and links. Thanks alot